# How can I write gerrit.config format?

Tags: java, http, config, devops, gerrit

### File `gerrit.config`

The audit configuration can be defined in the main gerrit.config
in a specific section dedicated to the audit-sl4j plugin.

gerrit.audit-sl4j.format
:   Output format of the audit record. Can be set to either JSON
    or CSV. By default, CSV.

gerrit.audit-sl4j.logName
:   Write audit to a separate log name under Gerrit logs directory.
    By default, audit records are put into the error_log.

How can I write the section gerrit.audit-sl4j.logName?
I have tried this :
But it doesn't work.

Comment: hi, check your question at "I have tried this:" . You probably didn't paste.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to paste the example that doesn't work for you. While you update it I can share a working example in case it can be of any help.

This is the `audit-sl4j` configuration part of a working `gerrit.config`:

```
[plugin "audit-sl4j"]
  format = JSON
  logName = audit_log
```

In this example, we are writing the audit logs to a file called `audit_log` in `JSON` format.

I hope this help.